# Express basicAuth: Async vs Syn

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect

I was wondering what the difference is between the async and sync callback patterns for basicAuth in connect.js middelware.

I understand the nodejs is on a single threaded event loop, but the synch "callback" is a callback function, and is thus asynchronous. So I don't understand what the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases your callback is actually called synchronously by `basicAuth`, but in the asynchronous case you call the `fn` parameter to your callback to deliver the result back to `basicAuth` instead of returning the result from your callback function.

Like shown in the canonical example code [from here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-basicAuth.html).

```
// Sync case, where the callback function returns true/false
connect(
  connect.basicAuth(function(user, pass){
    return 'tj' == user & 'wahoo' == pass;
  })
);

// Async case, where User.authenticate uses an asynchronous call to determine the validity
// of the user, and fn is called by that function to deliver the true/false result back to
// basicAuth once the async call completes.
connect(
  connect.basicAuth(function(user, pass, fn){
    User.authenticate({ user: user, pass: pass }, fn);
  })
);
```